# How to set a progressbar in setSmallIcon in Notificationbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, progress-bar

I have been trying to set make a circular progressbar in the Notification status bar. It is suppose to be a circular progressbar in Notification status bar. I was trying to find a simple way to build that but there was nothing really helpful.

What I have tried so far -

1. Try to create a dynamic bitmap and set it to the notification small icon but what I have read it setSmallIcon doesnt take bitmap and only int resources can be set.
2. Another way is to set the int resources dynamically as defined in the code below which works great but the problem here is I can't make 100 states of a circular progressbar to show progress ranging from 0-100. As a proof of concept I am changing five icons based on the values received from the viewmodel between 0-5

```
     myViewModel.getMeraki().observe(this,{
               Log.d("NotificationValue","Meraki ${it}")
               val merakiNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_1_ID).apply {
                   setContentTitle("Meraki ${it}")
                   val icon = resources.getIdentifier("ic_power_$it", "drawable", packageName)
                   setSmallIcon(icon)
                   priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
               }
   
   //            val PROGRESS_MAX = 100
               NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
   //                merakiNotification.setProgress(PROGRESS_MAX, it, false) 
   //                    .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                   notify(1, merakiNotification.build())
               }
   
           })
```

As you can see below the output of my current implementation working.

I am pretty sure there should be a simple way to do what I am trying to do it because android does it with battery icon in the status bar and shows the battery status from 0-100.

I need some guidance with this

[image]

Comment: "I can't make 100 states of a circular progressbar to show progress ranging from 0-100" -- why not? "android does it with battery icon in the status bar and shows the battery status from 0-100" -- that is not a notification and is not subject to the limits of notifications.

Comment: @CommonsWare First of all thank you for quick reply.  I feel that you might have misunderstood my comment.  What I meant is that it would be too many drawables if  I make 100 states of a simple progressbar. I didn't get your second comment.

Comment: Notification icons are not allowed to use custom drawable classes. The battery indicator is not a notification and they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so there is no way I can have my own progressive icon besides what I have proposed?